# Oracle 19C dbms_stats.gather_table_stats Slowness and return invalid identifier error

Tags: oracle

I'm are using Oracle 19C db and used to gather table stats.   dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(ownname =>'xx', tabname =>'yyy', cascade=>true, no_invalidate=>false);

it is too slow and some tables return following error as well.

ORA-00904 : invalid identifier.

Can assist find solution for this ? Row count around 80Millions

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this script. With my 19c Db it requires 50s for a table of 140milions rows and 30columns:

```
DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS (
   ownname=> 'xx',
   tabname=> 'yyy',
   estimate_percent=> DBMS_STATS.AUTO_SAMPLE_SIZE,
   block_sample=> FALSE,
   method_opt=> 'FOR ALL COLUMNS SIZE AUTO',
   degree=> DBMS_STATS.DEFAULT_DEGREE,
   granularity=> 'ALL',
   cascade=> DBMS_STATS.AUTO_CASCADE,
   no_invalidate=> DBMS_STATS.AUTO_INVALIDATE
   );
```

If it takes more time then you need verify indexes, triggers and constraints on your table.

Thank you.